# Logged in as : (your name) passed to another form using c# passing parameters

Tags: parameter-passing

When I use Microsoft C# windows forms application. I tried to run the login program then when I clicked the login button. it displays "Logged in as : (name of user)". then in the next form show I didn't see my name on the other form even I use some codes for the passing parameters like

Form1(codes)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string namesl;
    OleDbCommand cm;
    OleDbConnection cn;
    OleDbDataReader dr;

    string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =|DataDirectory|\10watts.accdb";


    public Form1( )
    {
        cn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();

        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void getName(string _getName) 
    {
    _getName = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
        cn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }




    private void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty || textBox2.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Missing Requirement Field!", "Unable to Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else 
        {
            timer1.Start();
            progressBar1.Visible = true;

        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 5;
            lblPercent.Text = progressBar1.Value + "%";
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                string sql = @"Select * from tblUser where Username like '" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password like '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
                cm = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Entered Logged In as : " + dr.GetValue(2).ToString(),"Successfully Logged in",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
           _getName = dr.getValue(2).toString();
                    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
                    frm2.Show();
                }
                else
                {


                }



            }
            else
            {

            }





    }
}
```

Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    OleDbConnection cn;
    OleDbDataReader dr;
    public string names;
    string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =|DataDirectory|\10watts.accdb";

    public Form2( )
    {
        cn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.loggedinform.getName(names);//this thing i worried about :/
    }
```

This whole code that I tried when I was using c# application.

Need your opinions or codes that may use for passing parameters :)